# 404 Error when deploying laravel on AWS EC2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I am trying to deploy Laravel on **Amazon EC2 (Linux AMI)**. I add `.htaccess` in the `larval` directory and `laravel/public` directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
WriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel/public/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I browser the `http://www.mydomaine.com/laravel/public`, the laravel first page works well, but when I browser into a sub page like `http://www.mydomaine.com/laravel/public/login`, a `404 Not Found` error appears. How to solve this problem, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Do no make any changes in a `.htaccess` file inside a `public` directory and do not add `.htaccess` to a Laravel root directory.

You need to point Laravel to a `public` directory to make it work. For example, if you've installed Laravel in `/path_to_laravel/public/` directory, you need to use these settings in your Apache config:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_laravel/public/"
<Directory "/path_to_laravel/public/">
```

After that restart Apache and your app should work as expected.

Use URLs, like `http://www.mydomaine.com/login` without 'laravel' and 'public'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is something else on my server. I want laravel application to be a subdirectory of my site.

Answer (score 0):

Doing as Alexey said should make it work.
However, if you really want your application to be in this specific path (`/laravel/public/`), you might add a new directive to your apache conf file.

Add a `ServerName "localhost.app/my/path"` and restart your Apache and it should work.